# Import error with Django Project

Tags: python, django

My Django project directory structure looks something like this:

```
/sparestub
//registration
//messages
//tickets
//requests
//venv
```

There are a bunch of other folders, but you get the idea. One of the modules installed in my virtual environment is requests. Notice that my app has a module named requests as well. The requests module is used by another module installed in my virtual environment called djrill. Whenever I try to start my server, I get the following error:

```
  File "/Users/me/Documents/coding/sparestub/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/djrill/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
from djrill.exceptions import MandrillAPIError, NotSupportedByMandrillError
  File "/Users/me/Documents/coding/sparestub/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/djrill/exceptions.py", line 1, in <module>
from requests import HTTPError
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPError'
```

What I suspect is happening that the djrill is trying to import my requests module instead of the requests module in my virtual environemnt and is failing because it doesn't have an HTTPError class.

My immediate guess was that my django website made it's way into PYTHONPATH. Looking at sys.path, I don't see anything incriminating. My app is called sparestub.

```
Python 3.4.1 (v3.4.1:c0e311e010fc, May 18 2014, 00:54:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/Users/me/Documents/coding/sparestub/venv/lib/python34.zip',
'/Users/me/Documents/coding/sparestub/venv/lib/python3.4',
'/Users/me/Documents/coding/sparestub/venv/lib/python3.4/plat-darwin',
'/Users/me/Documents/coding/sparestub/venv/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4',
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/plat-darwin',
'/Users/me/Documents/coding/sparestub/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages',
'/Users/me/Documents/coding/sparestub/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/newrelic-2.40.0.34']
```

Notice that the second to last line is for site-packages. I would expect the import requests statement to find the requests module here instead of my requests module. If you have any explanations as to why this is happening, I would love the help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can throw all your Django apps into `apps` folder, so that you refer them as `apps.requests`, that will no longer conflict with requests library.

Comment: I understand that I could namespace my apps, but why this necessary? Doesn't sys.path determine module resolution? If that's the case, why is the system finding my requests module before the one in virtual environment?

Comment: as far as I know, the working folder is always looked at first, i.e. '' in sys.path.

Comment: I ended up just changing the name of the app. The idea of redoing all of my imports sounded like a nightmare